# In Firefox, changing the focus in a keydown event handler automatically clicks what has been focused. How do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cPrSZ/2/

## HTML

```
<p>Space changes focus to button</p>
<button id="b1">Button1</button>
```

## JavaScript

```
var stopProp = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
};

$("#b1").on("click", function(event) {
    alert("Button1 Clicked");
    return stopProp(event);
});

$("body").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 32) {
        $("#b1").focus();
    }
    return stopProp(event);
});
```

In firefox, click on the paragraph so that the button loses focus.  Next, press space and you'll see that the button click gets triggered even though my code does not say to do that.  Why is this happening?

If I attach the handler on `$("p").on("keydown",` instead of `body`, things seem to work correctly, but I'm trying to avoid having to write a handler for each clickable element.  If I attach a "keyup" instead of "keypress" things work correctly, too.  But I'm making an html5 game and I want to be able to react to keypress instead of keyup for responsiveness sake.

Comment: `$("p").on("keydown"` does not trigger in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to change your keydown handler to a keyup handler. Here's why:

Firefox seems to be interpreting the combination of a keyup event while focus is applied as the same thing as a click.  I was able to overcome the problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mDyS/) with the following code:

```
$("body").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.target === document.getElementById('b1')) {
      return stopProp(event); 
    }
});
```

In this case, whenever there is a keyup, we check to see if it happened on the button. If so, we cancel it. This appears to cancel the unintended click.

Comment: Nice. And I think I can just `return stopProp(event);` without the if statement since I have no other keyup events in the first place, right?  That worked in my jsfiddle example, but I'm not sure what other ramifications that would have.

Comment: Correct. That'll do it :) Feel free to select the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked perfectly.  I was struggling with this for a whole day.  It doesn't have a noticeable effect on Chrome either which is great.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes Firefox (though I love 'em) can be a little wonky. I _think_ you'll be ok with this on IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyup event instead. This way the button is focused and not clicked.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hvdzv/

```
$("body").on("keyup", function(event) {
   if (event.which === 32) {
      $("#b1").focus();
   }
   return stopProp(event);
});
```

Comment: *Why* do I need to do this?  I'm not sure this is a good solution for me.  I'm making an HTML 5 game and it may negatively effect gameplay to change all the keypresses to keyups.

Comment: I thought it was some FF specific bug with focusing and the default behavior being executed though you return false. Just tried keyup in the fiddle. Can't really explain why this works im afraid, seems to be because keyup happens at a later time.

Comment: ah, also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859748/keydown-event-to-override-return-key-does-not-work-in-firefox

Comment: I'm not seeing how that link is relevant.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Checked answer, first comments. They had problems with return false and keydown in FF too.

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding Bugzilla ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220143